# Uncaught ReferenceError: OnSavedResultCb is not defined - Maxthon browsers

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, maxthon

I run a single page application and in my javascript error logs i found error related to Maxthon users.

UA: 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/4.4.5.1000 Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36`

My application blocks injection of non authorized third party scripts via "Content-Security-Policy" headers. (that's the reason of the exception )

I would like to know if `OnSavedResultCb` is a javascript function injected by Maxthon or by some plugin

Comment: Where did you see these logged errors? I've received a crash dump from a user on my system with a similar error, but never saw anything about the CSP headers. The error they received was "Uncaught ReferenceError: OnSavedResultCb is not defined" in the JavaScript console. No such function is called in any of my project's code. This question is the only hit on Google so far.

Comment: I log those errors using Bugsnag saas.

My webappapp blocks injection of third party javascripts setting CSP headers.

This should be a browser extension that tries to call the 'NOT' injected code

Comment: Ah, I started reading the CSP spec and saw where the browser can sendback errors to your server automatically (I don't use CSP myself - yet). My user claims there were no extensions added other than what Firefox and Chrome has, and users of those browsers on the exact same computer have no troubles. I can only conclude it to be Maxthon itself, but I can't find any documentation on what that function is even supposed to be.